# Derivative with prime for vector-valued function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider first the following vector-valued function of a real variable:

```
   s[t_] := {Sin[t], Cos[t]}
```

Then this works as expected:

```
   s'[t]
(* {Cos[t], -Sin[t]} *)
```

Why does the following use of prime to take derivative *not* also work?

```
   soln[t_] := {x[t], y[t]} /. 
  First@ DSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == y[t], 
     Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], 
     y[t]}, t]

   soln[t]
(* {Sin[t], Cos[t]} *)

   soln'[t]
(* During evaluation of In[89]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {First[{}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
D[{x[t], y[t]} /. First[{}], t]*)
```

Note that the following *does* work:

```
   D[soln[t], t]
(* {Cos[t], -Sin[t]} *)
```

Comment: `soln[t] := ...` should be `soln[t_] := ... ` (notice the undescore after the `t`).

Comment: The missing underscore was purely a typo, now fixed in the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought this was just about order of operations, and it is largely that, but there is an added twist I'll get to.

First, let me note you've defined `soln` using `SetDelayed`.  I think that is a mistake because it means `DSolve` is reevaluated every single time you evaluate `soln`.  If that's slow, `soln` will be very slow.  In fact, I'd define `soln` as follows

```
soln[t_] = DSolveValue[Derivative[1][x][t] == y[t], Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

Now, as for your mystery.  When you evaluate `soln'[t]`, this is interpreted as

```
Derivative[1][soln][t]
```

Okay, what's the derivative of soln?  It's going to be computed as

```
D[soln[someVar], someVar]
```

Well, that looks very innocent, but the question is what is `someVar`?  It depends on the version exactly what temporary expression `Derivative` uses, but critically this temporary variable is going into `DSolve`, not the solution, beacuse you've used `SetDelayed` to define `soln`. Moreover, the temporary expression is something that will prevent `DSolve` from evaluating successfully.  In V12.1, `DSolve` returns an empty list, which means `First[DSolve[...]]` won't evaluate, which means `/.` won't evaluate, and you get the output above.  And if you think about, trying to run `DSolve`, which solves things about derivatives, while in the process of actually computing a derivative, is going to problematic at best.

When you use `D[soln[t],t]`, since `D` isn't a holding function, `soln[t]` evaluates to `{Sin[t], Cos[t]}` before `D` ever sees it, and you're fine.

Finally, had you defined `soln` using `Set`, then `someVar` would have been substituted into `{Sin[t], Cos[t]}` rather than the original `DSolve` expression, and everything would also have been fine.  This is another reason why it is typically better to use `Set` when you are substituting output from a solver into an expression.

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to clarify the mystery here. The way you defined `soln[t]`, without the underscore, means that the delayed expansion will **only** work when you use symbol `t` as the argument:

```
soln[u]
(* soln[u] - it returns unevaluated *)
```

When you type `D[soln[t],t]`, you are just lucky that the first argument evaluates to `{Sin[t], Cos[t]}`, which gets differentiated. If you try any other letter, e.g.

```
D[soln[u],u]
(* Derivative[1][soln][u] *)
```

it returns unchanged.

Answer (score 5):

This works in Mathematica 12.0

```
Remove[soln, t, x, y]

soln[tau_] := DSolveValue[ {
   Derivative[1][x][t] == y[t], 
   Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t], 
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1 }, 
   { x[tau], y[tau] }, t]

soln[t]
(*  {Sin[t], Cos[t]}  *)

soln'[t]
(*  {Cos[t], -Sin[t]}  *)
```

Don't know why your example doesn't work.

Comment: The solution by LouisB also works if you use `x

Comment: This works because it distinguishes the variable of soln (tau) from the variable used to specify the DE, so DSolveValue can still evaluate--it subsitutes the temporary expression for tau in at the end.  See my answer...

Answer (score 5):

Besides the underscore, the problem is the SetDelayed `:=` .

```
{soln[t_] = {x[t], y[t]} /. 
First@DSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == y[t], 
  Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], 
  y[t]}, t],
soln[t],
soln'[t]}

(*   {{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {Cos[t], -Sin[t]}}   *)
```

Let me say, many user here think, SetDelayed is the best way to define nearly everything. The opposite is true. Use it as less as absolutly necessary.

Comment: `SetDelayed is the best way to define nearly everything. The opposite is true. Use it as less as absolutly necessary.` main problem with using set for function definitions is as shown in possible issues under Set. If one has global symbol already has value, then it will fail. `ClearAll[x];x = 5;f[x_] = x^2;f[2]` this gives `25` instead of expected `4`. Using SetDelayed solves these problems. So for me `:=` is just more safe to use as general otherwise one needs to make sure symbols used  in definition of Set are cleared before.

Comment: I think, there are a lot of possibilities to avoid global symbol definition, e.g. `With` , `Module `,  `ReplaceAll ` ...  And there is undocumented agreement, to reserve symbls like x,y,z, t,u,v ...for varialble definition. With SetDelayed a lot of errors are reported, because the effect of following operators was not taken into account.